# Why does the error "At st-cuts.c:415 : Invalid root vertex id for dominator tree, Invalid value" occur in the stCuts?

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following matrix EdgesGroep as input for graph.adjacency (sorry for the ugly way of giving the matrix):

```
 [1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0
 [2,] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0
 [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0
 [4,] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0
 [5,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1  1  1  0  0
 [6,] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0
 [7,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  1  0  0
 [8,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1  1  0
 [9,] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0
[10,] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1  0  1  0  0
[11,] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0  1  0  0  0
[12,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0
[13,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0

EdgesGroep <- as.matrix(EdgesGroep)
colnames(EdgesGroep) <- 1:dim(EdgesGroep)[1]
g1 <- graph.adjacency(EdgesGroep, mode="directed", weighted=NULL)
tkplot(g1)
V <- V(g1)
E <- get.edgelist(g1)
mode(E) <- "integer"
stCuts(g1, source=V[7], target=V[8])
```

Then the error occurs

> Error in stCuts(g1, source = V[7], target = V[8]) : 
>         At st-cuts.c:415 : Invalid root vertex id for dominator tree, Invalid value

I actually want to obtain the cuts between all pair of nodes. I already have code to do that, but then the stCuts function should work.

Can anyone help discovering what to do to fix the error?

Comment: For many (source,target) combinations it works to switch the order:

st_cuts(g1, source=V[8], target=V[11]) does not work but st_cuts(g1, source=V[11], target=V[8]) does work.

 (source,target) combinations that do not work that way are (9,11) , (10,11) and (7, 8-11). I have no idea why the switched order for some combinations work and others does not...

Comment: This is a bug in the igraph C core: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1102